# Unable to Post a remote loaded form data to a database using jquery ajax post method

Tags: php, jquery, sql, html

Gudday guys,I have a little challenge posting a form successful to a database after loading the form remotely using jquery's `load()` method,it worked in google chrome but not working using firefox.Thanks in anticipation of your help.

PHP Code.

```
<?php
        include 'login.php';
  if( isset($_POST['c_title']) && isset($_POST['c_code']) && isset($_POST['staff_id'])&& isset($_POST['staff_fulname'])
  && isset($_POST['c_desc'])&& isset($_POST['unit']) ){

      $c_title = sanitize_string($_POST['c_title']);
      $c_code = sanitize_string($_POST['c_code']); 
      $staff_id = sanitize_string($_POST['staff_id']);
      $staff_fulname= sanitize_string($_POST['staff_fulname']); 
      $c_desc = sanitize_string($_POST['c_desc']);
      $unit = sanitize_string($_POST['unit']); 



      $sql = " insert into course values('$c_title','$c_code','$staff_id','$staff_fulname','$c_desc','$unit') ";

      $result = mysql_query($sql);

      if($result){
        // echo '<br/> <div align="center"><small class="alert alert-success">&radic; Saved Successfully!</small></div>';
        echo '<script>alert("Saved Successfully!");</script>';
      }
      else{
          echo '<script>alert("Error Occured!");</script>';
      }



  }

   function sanitize_string($var){
    $var = mysql_real_escape_string($var);
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    $var = stripslashes($var);

    return $var;
   }
  ?>

<body>




<div class="container5">
<div align="center"><h3 class="btn-danger">Course Details</h3></div>
<div class="row">

<div class="span12">

<br/>
<div class="row">
<form id ="course_form" action="" method="post">
<div class="span6">
<div align="center">
Course Title:<input type="text" name="c_title" required/>
</div></div>

<div align="right">
<div class="span6">
Course Code:<input type="text" name="c_code" required/>
</select>
</div>
</div></div></div>
</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="span12">

<div class="row">


<div class="span6">
<div align="center">
Staff ID:<input type="text" name="staff_id" required/>
</div></div>
<div class="span6">
<div align="right">
Staff FullName:<input type="text" name="staff_fulname" required/>
</div></div>
<br/>
</div></div></div>

<div class="row">

<div class="span12">

<div class="row">


<div class="span6">
<div align="center">
Course Description:<textarea name ="c_desc" rows="3"></textarea>
</div></div>
<div class="span6">
<div align="right">
Unit Load:<select name="unit"> <option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>6</option> </select></div>
</div>
<br/>
</div></div></div>

<div align="center"><button id="save2" class=" btn btn-danger">Save</button>
</form>

</div>
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#save2").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
        url: "course.php",
        data: $('#course_form').serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
                  alert("Saved Successfully");
                },
        error: function(){
            alert("Error has occurred");
            return
        }
            });
         })
});
         </script>
```

Comment: not sure what you mean by loading page remotely, do you mean that saving script and HTML are on different domains? try to use fiddler or web tracker to see what request form is sending to server.